# My cubit is not emitting a new state with freezed?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I am trying to use Cubit for state management and I have a state class with `@freezed` annotation. I've used cubits before and did not see any issues like that before. In cubit constructor I emit initial state with super constructor and `BLocBuilder` catches that initial state. Then, whenever I emit a new state, my cubit is actually not emitting. Here is how my code looks like:

`promotion_state.dart`

```dart
part of 'promotion_cubit.dart';

@freezed
abstract class PromotionState with _$PromotionState {
  const factory PromotionState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory PromotionState.loaded({required TrophyIconType trophyIconType}) = _Loaded;
}
```

`promotion_cubit.dart`

```dart
Future<void> whenMenuPageDisplayed() async {
  emit(const PromotionState.loaded(trophyIconType: TrophyIconType.withAnimation));
}
```

`menu_page.dart`

```dart
return BlocProvider<PromotionCubit>(
      create: (_) => getIt<PromotionCubit>()..init(),
      child: BlocBuilder<PromotionCubit, PromotionState>(
        builder: (context, state) => state.maybeWhen(
          initial: () => const SizedBox.shrink(),
          loaded: (trophyIconType) {
            print(state);
            return _TrophyIcon(trophyIconType);
          },
          orElse: () => const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Where I am calling `whenMenuPageDisplayed` function:

```dart
@injectable
class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  MyNavigatorObserver(this._promotionCubit);

  final PromotionCubit _promotionCubit;

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (route.settings.name == '/menu') {
      _promotionCubit.whenMenuPageDisplayed();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute!.settings.name == '/menu') {
      _promotionCubit.whenMenuPageDisplayed();
    }
  }
}
```

`print(state);` in Loaded state is not displaying any output in the terminal.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the `whenMenuPageDisplayed` function?

Comment: I 've added the function.

Comment: check if the function is being called with a true if statement by adding a print statement inside the if block.

Comment: It is actually called bc other functionalities in whenMenuPageDisplayed func. are working (not in the example).

Comment: With this design, there might be a chance that you might be injecting two different cubits to `MyNavigatorObserver` and the `BlocProvider`. Can you confirm that the cubit is annotated with @singleton

Comment: It is weird. It was annotedted with `injectable` and I am trying to make it `singleton`. get_it gives me an error in this case. I'll find the issue.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I've used `@lazySingleton` annotation and it works, thanks.

Comment: @singleton + build_runner + app restart - and it works!

Answer (score 3):

For those who stumbled upon this question while doing a google search, the problem was that getIt was creating new instances of the cubit when it was requested.

The solution was to annotate the cubit class with @singleton or @lazySingleton in the authors case.

Comment: @shuster can you mark this answer as correct so others can quickly use it instead of going through our comment thread.

Comment: you have to give more detail by using code examples.

Comment: i got the same problem. please help explain with code